# Flutter URL Launcher Google Maps Multiple Maker

Tags: flutter, google-maps, android-launcher, app-launcher

How can launch google map with multiple marker in flutter
I use map-launcher but it only shows me only one marker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) package

passing set of markers and the map widget can handle it

```
GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
                target: LatLng(-33.852, 151.211),
                zoom: 11.0,
              ),
              markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
            ),
```

Comment: thanks , but I need open Google maps with multiple marker not in my app

Comment: aha if you want it as url you can add it as direction 
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/33.93729,-106.85761/33.91629,-106.866761/33.98729,-106.85861/33.93729,-106.85761/33.91629,-106.866761/33.98729,-106.85861/@33.9599902,-106.8698812,12.75z